# notifyDataSetChanged() performance question and when/how to call in relation to a batch of data changes

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have ArrayList of custom objects that is the data underlying an ArrayAdapter for a ListView.

Sometimes this data is modified in a batch, such as fetching a set of new items from the web.  When the data is modified in a batch, should notifyDataSetChanged() be called after every add() to the ArrayList

*Some over simplified code:*

```
for(Object object : newObjects){
   list.add(object);
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

or should it be called once after all of the items in the batch have been added?

```
for(Object object : newObjects){
    list.add(object);
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Say there is a batch of 50 new objects.  If 50 notifyDataSetChanged() calls are made right after another, like in the first example, will the views redraw themselves 50 times in a row (I imagine a major performance hit) or will it only perform the latest call and in a sense only redraw them once?

I'm basically wondering if I can use the first method or will it have a major performance impact?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call notifyDataSetChanged(), it doesn't redraw the view immediately. It's up to the UI thread controller to know when to redraw. Although it does *appear* instantanious. You should try it and see if there's a performance issue. We really can't answer that for you. If it makes sense to only update the listview after all the adds, then do that.